# What does the "fortune-telling" slot-machine do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

There's this new slot:
[image: Fortune telling]

What does it do? I've spent some cents only to receive cryptic phrases. The best use I've found for them is blowing them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with the slot in the image, and with the help of the [wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/The_Binding_of_Isaac%3A_Wrath_of_the_Lamb), I've found that, in addition to the cryptic sentences, there are also a lot of useful rewards including:

- trinkets
- Tarot cards
- Playing cards (especially useful the two of diamonds, that doubles your current amount of coins)
- soul hearts
- a Crystal Ball (probably on blowup), a usable item that reveals the map and spawns a random card or a soul heart (thanks @Keaanu!)

Here you can see my results after playing for a while (I failed to make it blow up by itself, so I used a bomb):

[image: fortune blow]

It can become a little cluttered, as you can see. I also had 3 more soul hearts and 1 heart container, but I wanted to kill the boss before finishing my experiments.

Comment: [The wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/The_Binding_of_Isaac:_Wrath_of_the_Lamb) also states that the Fortune Telling Machine eventually drops the Crystal Ball, a usable item which "reveals the map and gives a random card or soul heart."